# Recycler inside the viewholder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Hi friends please help me i am using the recycle view which having one heading and another horizontal recycle view where i am populating the data with Json my problem is that in the horizontal recycle view i am getting only last value in the please find the below code.

Here layout that need

[image]

Menu_Item_List.java

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cater_bg"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Break Fast"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_rv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Menu.java

```
public class Menu_Fragment extends Fragment {
    @BindView(R.id.menu_rv)
    RecyclerView menu_rv;
    FastItemAdapter<Menu_List_Item> menu_item_adapter = new FastItemAdapter<>();


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        menu_rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        menu_rv.setAdapter(menu_item_adapter);
        menu_list();
    }

    private void menu_list() {
//        String menuurl = Constant.aloourl + "shop_menu&vendor_id=" + getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("catergoryid") + "&type=2";
        String menuurl = Constant.aloourl + "shop_menu&vendor_id=32&type=2";
        Constant.l(menuurl);
        AndroidNetworking.get(menuurl).build().getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray menuarray = response.getJSONArray("mlist");
                    for (int i = 0; i < menuarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject menuobjarray = menuarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Iterator menuiterator = menuobjarray.keys();
                        while (menuiterator.hasNext()) {
                            String menuname = (String) menuiterator.next();
                            Menu_List_Item menulist = new Menu_List_Item();
                            menulist.setMenuname(menuname);
                            JSONArray menuarrayname = menuobjarray.getJSONArray(menuname);
                            for (int j = 0; j < menuarrayname.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject menunameobjs = menuarrayname.getJSONObject(j);
                                Menu_Item_Adapter mealslist = new Menu_Item_Adapter();
                                mealslist.setMenu_item_id(menunameobjs.getString("mid"));
                                mealslist.setMenu_item_name(menunameobjs.getString("item"));
                                mealslist.setMenu_item_price(menunameobjs.getString("price"));
                                mealslist.setMenu_item_image(menunameobjs.getString("restaurant_subimage"));
                                menulist.setMenu_adapter(mealslist);
                            }
                            menu_item_adapter.add(menulist);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Constant.l(e.toString());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ANError anError) {
                Constant.l(anError.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Menu_Adapter.java

```
public class Menu_List_Item extends AbstractItem<Menu_List_Item, Menu_List_Item.Menu_List_Item_ViewHolder> {

    String menuname;
    Menu_Item_Adapter menu_adapter;

    public String getMenuname() {
        return menuname;
    }

    public void setMenuname(String menuname) {
        this.menuname = menuname;
    }

    public Menu_Item_Adapter getMenu_adapter() {
        return menu_adapter;
    }

    public void setMenu_adapter(Menu_Item_Adapter menu_adapter) {
        this.menu_adapter = menu_adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public Menu_List_Item_ViewHolder getViewHolder(View v) {
        return new Menu_List_Item_ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return R.id.menu_item_rv;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.menu_list_item;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(Menu_List_Item_ViewHolder holder, List<Object> payloads) {
        super.bindView(holder, payloads);
        holder.menu_name.setText(menuname);
        holder.menu_item_rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(holder.itemView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        FastItemAdapter<Menu_Item_Adapter> menu_item_adapters=new FastItemAdapter<>();
        menu_item_adapters.add(menu_adapter);
        holder.menu_item_rv.setAdapter(menu_item_adapters);

    }

    public static class Menu_List_Item_ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.menu_name)
        AppCompatTextView menu_name;
        @BindView(R.id.menu_item_rv)
        RecyclerView menu_item_rv;

        public Menu_List_Item_ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can do it using just requires single recylerview. set item type in recylerview in first itemview for header and second itemview you can use horizontal scrollview.

Comment: u say that i can use two layout right ?@Vij

Comment: yes bcoz it is easier way

Comment: can please give me some clear please i had tried ur way but i am getting only vertical layout @Vij

Comment: check my ans for items layout use horizontal scrollview to get horizontal scroll

Comment: also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247414/dynamically-add-to-horizontalscrollview  to add items in horizontal scroll view in ItemsViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a nested recycler view inside main recycler view i.e inside main layout add anaother recycler view and horizontal recycler items inside that recycler view.Create horizontal recyclerview inside main recyclerview like this

```
public class SampleRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

public SampleRecyclerView() {
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.YOUR_MAIN_LAYOUT, parent, false);
    return new SampleViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final SampleViewHolder viewHolder = (SampleViewHolder) holder;

    //Update your Horizontal views here into adapter
    notifyDataSetChanged();


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return YOUR_LIST.size();
}

private class SampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private YOUR_HORIZONTAL_ADAPTER mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public SampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mAdapter = new YOUR_HORIZONTAL_ADAPTER(mClassName, mMovieItems.get(Integer.toString(position)));
        mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(mContext,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);

        YOUR_HORIZONTAL_RECYCLER_VIEW.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        YOUR_HORIZONTAL_RECYCLER_VIEW.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

  }
}
```

**EDIT**:I have made some changes to your existing recycler view adapter.Your nested recycler view should be updated like this.

```
public class Menu_List_Item extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<Menu_List_Items_Pojo> menu_list_pojo_items;


public Menu_List_Item(Activity activity, ArrayList<Menu_List_Items_Pojo> menu_list_pojo_items) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.menu_list_pojo_items = menu_list_pojo_items;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, parent, false);
    return new Menu_List_Item_ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Menu_List_Items_Pojo menulistitempojo = menu_list_pojo_items.get(position);
    Menu_List_Item_ViewHolder viewholder = (Menu_List_Item_ViewHolder) holder;
    viewholder.menu_name.setText(menulistitempojo.getMenu_name());

    //Call this method with different positions
    viewholder.setDataToAdapter(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return menu_list_pojo_items.size();
}


 public class Menu_List_Item_ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.menu_name)
    AppCompatTextView menu_name;
    @BindView(R.id.menu_item_rv)
    RecyclerView menu_item_rv;
    ArrayList<Menu_Item_Adapter>itemsAdapter=new ArrayList<>();
    Menu_Item_Adapter meudap = new Menu_Item_Adapter();


    public Menu_List_Item_ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        menu_item_rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(itemView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        menu_item_rv.setAdapter(menu_adapter);
    }

    //Change data value each time when onBindViewHolder is called
    public void setDataToAdapter(int position) {
        for(int i=0;i<menu_list_pojo_items.size();i++){
            meudap.setMenu_item_id(menu_list_pojo_items.get(position).getMenu_mid());
            meudap.setMenu_item_image(menu_list_pojo_items.get(position).getMenu_restaurant_image());
            meudap.setMenu_item_name(menu_list_pojo_items.get(position).getMenu_item());
            meudap.setMenu_item_price(menu_list_pojo_items.get(position).getMenu_price());
            itemsAdapter.add(meudap);

        }
        menu_adapter.add(itemsAdapter);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155617/discussion-on-answer-by-anonymous-recycler-inside-the-viewholder). Please incorporate all relevant information back into the answer, by [edit]ing.

Answer (score 0):

set type in your list  like  YourModel.setType(1)

list.add(YourModel);

```
 public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

 private ArrayList<YourModel> list = new ArrayList<YourModel>();

  class HeaderViewHolder extends ViewHolder {

     public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

    }
}

class ItemsVideHolder extends ViewHolder {
    public ItemsVideHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

    }
}

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

       int type = list.get(position).getType();

        //1 for header
        if(type == 1){

        }

        //2 for items
       else if(type == 2){

        }
        return position ;
    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View viewItem;
        switch (viewType) {
            case 1:
                viewItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_layout, parent, false);
                ViewHolder vh = new HeaderViewHolder(viewItem);
                return vh;
            case 2:
                viewItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_layout, parent, false);
                ViewHolder vh1 = new ItemsVideHolder(viewItem);
                return vh1;

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case 0:
                HeaderViewHolder viewHolder0 = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
                break;

            case 2:
               ItemsVideHolder viewHolder2 = (ItemsVideHolder) holder;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok bro i understand your problem you have only one list so bro sorry for my understanding you can use direct one view  in which your header and horizontal scrollview not require two view items in your adapter

Comment: set menu name in your header and items in your horizontal scrollview

Comment: i am using recycler view bro

Comment: i see your code   menu_adapter.add(meudap); where menu_adapter is list? menu_item_rv.setAdapter(menu_adapter);

Comment: its described in the view holders